# How to get Ember compoment's "ID" attribute?

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js

I am using a ember components in a recursive manner and im going to make particular components as draggable in jquery-ui. so,i need to get its corresponding view id like "ember143" for the following HTML view,

```
<div id="ember143" class="ember-view"></div>
```

is there a way to get the id attribute?

NOTE: i know i cant set a unique class name to get its view element by

```
var Component = Ember.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ["uniqueClassName"],
  uniqueClassName: 'class143'
});
```

if it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember Component has a `elementId` property which returns the `id` of the element in the DOM.
so you can get the component's id using `this.get('elementId').
More info here:
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#property_elementId

Comment: Ember test selector plugin https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors for generating test ids helped me.